# Build HTML with inputs from Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to build a small application that dynamically builds a series of html cards using Materialize CSS based on fields that are present in a google sheet. I've provided a link to the example app, and the example sheet below.

sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DD3wqB3IhvReJ5CWVHC-nYAqbphmlzhXYcNzLrgkzUc/edit#gid=0
app:https://script.google.com/a/macros/ampion.net/s/AKfycbxqxsaUMo_hCUg6qURToC1eTMjhTmQ7EEjwyLJM5XRLzj4q5tI2/exec

You should be able to disregard the server side functions `doGet` `readData` `writeData` but I have kept them to ensure example remains functional.

The client function `getData` is supposed to place the data coming in from the sheet into the appropriate location in the card. I believe this is where things are breaking down.

I've included two sections in the HTML body, the first section is `<div id="div"></div><br><br>` and is meant to be where the html is dynamically attached via the `id="div"`. The next section is everything that follows below, which is meant to be the card template that I have provided as an example of what I want the cards to look like once they have been built.

You can see that once the cards are built into the `<div id="div"></div><br><br>`, they lose their formatting and functionality; you can't click on the card to reveal the contents, the layout is broken, and there's a `NaN` error.

I have attempted to provide only the code required to fully present the problem and provide you with a functional example to work from. I think you will find that the code has already been minimized.

Thank you so much for your help!

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  function readData() {
    var range = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 1,spreadsheet.getLastRow(), spreadsheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    Logger.log(range);
    return range;
};
  
  
  function writeData(sendvalue) {
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getLastRow()+1, 1).activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getLastRow()+1, 1).setValue(sendvalue);

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
      <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div id="div"></div><br><br>
    
         <div class="activator main">
         <div class="activator card blue-grey darken-1" >
            <div class="activator card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
               <span class="activator card-title deep-orange-text text-lighten-1">Information Security<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
               <p class="activator deep-orange-text text-lighten-1" >Learn about the secuirty posture of our business, learn how to be a human firewall, request access on a new system, draw attention to a potential security threat.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-reveal">
               <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4"><i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
               <span class="card-title activator deep-orange-text text-lighten-1">Information Security<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
        
    <script>
    function getData(values) {
    values.forEach(function(item, index) {
    var x = document.getElementById("div");
    x.innerHTML += '<div class="activator main">'+
         '<div class="activator card blue-grey darken-1">'+
            +'<div class="activator card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">'
            +'</div>'+
            '<div class="card-content">'+
              '<span class="activator card-title deep-orange-text text-lighten-1">' + item[0] + '<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>'+'<p class="activator deep-orange-text text-lighten-1">'+item[1]+'</p>'+'</div>'+'<div class="card-reveal">'+'<span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4"><i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>'+'<span class="card-title activator deep-orange-text text-lighten-1">'+item[0]+'<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>'+'</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>';
    });
    }
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getData).readData();
    
    
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54207155/7215091

Comment: The NaN seems to be that the `item[0]` does not have anything in there and for the functionality, the html from those that don't work is different from the main one, have you checked on that?

Comment: But item[0] is showing up! That's everything in column 1 in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Have you checked on using it like on the @Cooper comment? They are passing the data like here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets