# how to append html page inside current page using google web app?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, partials

I know how to include CSS or JS files using app script in a web script. but that way includes files content on page lode.

**My question is it possible to include partial html page inside the currently opened page?**

app script to include CSS or JS

```
/* @Include JavaScript & CSS & HTML-Partial-Views  */
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

and I use like this

```
<?!= include('Css'); ?>
```

and here is my attempt.

html

```
<button onclick="getList("users")">show some html content</button> 
<div id="users"></div>
<script>
function getList(users){
   var listUsers = google.script.run.showHtml(users);
   // how to return showHtml result [list of users]
   for (var i; i <= listUsers.length; 1++)
   {
      document.querySelector("#users").innerHTML += <div>listUsers[i]</div>; 
   }
 }
</script>
```

gs

```
function users(sheetName, pageName){
   // get users from sheet
   var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById("435yh35h45b35nh6hg5bwh455j");
   var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
   var dataRange = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
   return dataRange;
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `My question is it possible to include partial html page inside the currently opened page?`, I cannot understand the situation for adding the HTML. For example, will you add the HTML to the current page by clicking a button? And, in your expected goal, in order to add your showing `html` to the current HTML page, the page is reopened? Or, do you want to achieve this without reopening the page?

Comment: yes @Tanaike exactly. I want to include html without reopening the current page. For example: my current page is `Index.Html` and I want to include list of users from `Users.Html` without refresh or reopening `Index.Html` again

Comment: I want to call list of users by clicking a button which will call app script function to return list of users to `users.Html` and then I get that structure to my current page `Index.Html`

Comment: create anotther div and request the server to load the div with an html string generated  on the server.  You don't have to create another page but if you wish you can always create a dialog.

Comment: would you please help my @Cooper via code sample. I already have `#users` the div where I want to list the retrieved data. but I don't know how to trigger `google.script.run.showHtml` by a button click and get the returned html to include inside `#users`

Comment: Here's a simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54207155/7215091)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood that you wanted to add the HTML by clicking a button. But, I cannot still understand your situation. In your situation, do you want to add only HTML without including Javascript? Or, do you want to add HTML including Javascript?

Comment: in a very simple way, I'm now in `index.html`  I want to get html content of `users.html` and show in  `index.html`. for example: i want to click `#btn` to run app script function `google.script.run.getusers` and then in `getusers` function I want to get html content by return html with users list data retrieved from sheet like this `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("users").getContent();` ----> `users.html` contains for example `inside for loop ...<ul><li><?= userName ?></li><li><?= userPhone ?></li><li><?= userAddress ?></li></ul>`

Comment: i want to call this function by button click and retrieve result in web page. ` function include(filename) {return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();}`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Can you provide a sanitized copy of your project? Without it, it is difficult to view what you are trying to achieve exactly. It seems that you don't need to include a partial HTML more than calling a function that construct this table from outside, as the [@Ruben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71730960/14271633) shown

Answer (score 1):

From one of the code snippets

> ```
> // how to return showHtml result [list of users]
> ```

Try this:

```html
<button onclick="getList('users')">show some html content</button> 
<div id="users"></div>
<script>
function getList(users){
   var listUsers = google.script.run
     .withSuccessHandler((listUsers) => {
       let list = '';
       for (var i; i < listUsers.length; i++) {
          list += `<div>${listUsers[i]}</div>\n`; 
       }
       document.querySelector("#users").innerHTML = list;
     })
     .showHtml(users);
   
 }
</script>
```

Changes done

1. Replaced `"users"` by `'users'`
2. Added `withSuccessHandler` with an arrow function as callback.
   The arrow function build a string using a `for` statement (because it was used in the original code) including a `div` tag using a template literal.